# USB Drives Inaccessible to Multiple Users

Tags: usb, mount, multi-user

My Ubuntu install is mounting USBs just fine, but the only user who can access it is the one who plugged it in to the PC--which is rather problematic since this is a family computer which is in a really awkward spot, so having to unplug and replug the stick between users is annoying. Why wouldn't every user be able to access the contents of the stick?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is take out the usb and plug it back in! That should fix your problem, as for why this specific feature/problem/annoyance exists? I think it is for security reasons.

Comment: I know that, but I'd like to disable the feature anyway.

Comment: @BarneyFifeFan I am not sure how that would be done sorry